# Javascript isn't interacting with a div how I intend it to

Tags: javascript, html

DISCLAIMER: I am a complete and total noob at this so please don't scream at me if I miss something obvious.

I am trying to get an external javascript file to update a  element but it keeps giving me the following error:
*Uncaught ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call*
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <body>
   <script src="magic.js"></script>
    <button onclick="detclic()"></button>
     <div id="htmldivone"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The javascript code:

```
var i = 2;
var e = 1;
var o = e * 2;
function detclic() {
if (o <= i) {
i = i - o;
document.getElementById("htmldivone").innerHTML = o;
}
}
```

Basically I would give the variable i a value of 2 and it would take 3 tries to get the  element to update, I can't figure out why. Help?
(This is just some silly minigame I'm making before you ask.)

Comment: You are declaring `i = 0` and `o = 2`, then you ask `if o is less than or equal to i`, that would never happen since `o` is already greater than `i` (maybe some other part of the code is decrementing `o`?)

Comment: Your if condition is never met, you only assign `i` inside if block

Comment: Which specific line is producing that error?

Comment: @David line 7 of the javascript code

Comment: @arieljuod I gave i a value of 2 before I pressed the button thats not where the issue is its where "document.getElementById().innerHTML" is on line 7

Comment: @Yablu: I get no such error: https://jsfiddle.net/2ubo65cg/  Perhaps you could modify your example and create a runnable code snippet in the question which would demonstrate?

Comment: your if statmen is wrong. It always will return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
<button onclick="detclic()"></button>
```

you reference the `detclic()` function which *then* references `#htmldivone`

even though, at this point, the parser has not yet reached:

```
<div id="htmldivone"></div>
```

nor parsed the `detclic()` function.

---

**Alternative approach:**

An alternative - and arguably cleaner - approach to using an inline event listener like `onclick="detclic()"` is:

- remove `onclick="detclic()"` from your HTML; and
- use `addEventListener` in your script instead

like this:

```
const myButton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
myButton.addEventListener('click', detclic, false);
```

Comment: wow thats a suprisingly simple solution to the problem I thought was so complicated XD
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is never going to be executed since your first condition **if (o <= i)**  is never true when **o** is equal to 2 and **i** is equal to zero.

The second error is that you are decrementing the value of **i** without looping the code in your function, so **i** will always have the same value.

Can you please explain more what do you need to do exactly need to do with your script ?

Comment: I want the div to update to the value of o when the button is pressed, but the div needs to be pressed twice for that to happen, its de-synced, but I cant figue out why.
also, for get the i variable or assume its value is 2.